# How to load a GlobalKTable from a topic without key?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When I need to load a topic with no key as a `kTable`, I usually consume the topic as a `kStream`, remap it to extract a key/value, and use a `kGroupedStream` in order to build the `kTable` and its store:

```
KStream<String, String> mappingStream = builder
      .stream(TOPIC_MAPPING_IN, consumed)
      .map(
          (key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(
              value.get("my_key").asText(), 
              value.get("my_value").asText())
       );

KGroupedStream<String, String> mappingGroupedStream = mappingStream.groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String() ));

KTable<String,String> mappingTable = mappingGroupedStream.aggregate(
      () -> "", //initializer 
      (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> newValue,  
      Materialized.<String, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(MY_MAPPINGS_STORE)
          .withValueSerde(Serdes.String())
          .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
       );
```

Now, we are beginning to partition our topics, and I try to take advantage of the `GlobalKTable`, but the only way I found to forge a `GlobalKTable` is by doing a `builder.globalTable(...)`.

I guess it would work if we'd write an app that loads data from the `topic_in_WITHOUT_key`, forges the key, and publishes to a `topic_in_WITH_key`. And the `GlobalKTable` is loaded from this `topic_in_WITH_key`.

Is it the only way?

My main concern with this solution is to have someone to create/configure the intermediate topic, with possible mistakes. In the case I presented in introduction with the `kTable`, the `changelog` topic acted as the intermediate topic, but this `changelog-topic` is automatically created by the app, with the appropriate configuration.

Comment: You will need to create a new topic, and re-key the data as you described. The topic you use should be configure with log compaction to guard agains data loss -- what actually indicates that you are doing something non-optimal: your original topic should be configured with log compaction, too, but I assume it's not, because there are no keys. Thus, loading this data into a (Global)KTable might result in data loss. The "issue" you are seeing is an indicator of some gaps in your setup.

Comment: And you are right Matthias, my original topic is not configured with log compaction. But I am pretty sure I do not want to apply a log compaction on this original topic :) Because publishers provide "delta" data in this topic ( msg1: `Key1 - {attrib_A: val_A, attrib_B:val_B}` / msg2: `Key1 - {attrib_C: val_C, attrib_B: new_Val_B}` . With log compaction, `msg1` would disappear before msg2, and the information about `attrib_A` would be lost forever.
 So I feel I have to have the new topic, in order to store the full state, with log compaction.

Comment: Just a last question.... Why do you write `Thus, loading this data into a (Global)KTable might result in data loss.` ? As long as my original topic is with infinite retention, data cannot be lost, may this topic be configured with or withut log compaction, right?

Comment: Yes, if retention time in infinite, data loss should not occur. As I said: "might" :)